# multiple lines in a cell in web scraping

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib

I am trying to download a table that has, in a single cell, multiple items.
I get three problems:

1. the tracklist column is not correctly generated (it is in a following row insted ot the same row as the other datatype (as written in headers)];
2. songs within the last column (tracklist) are not embedded in one cell and I couldn't find a way to get rid of multiple lines formatting;
3. The download stops at year 1990 for an error

   > "UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x91' in position 2886: character maps to < undefined >"

   I found some answers but I still can't understand how to definitely solve the issue. I had the same problem yesterday and, by reading online, it seems that it involves weird character not recognized by the system. Isn't there a way to solve the problem definitely (I will export csv for excel use).

This is the code (after I tried suggestion from @Anurag):

```
import codecs
import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
import unicodecsv as csv
years = list(range(1965,2016))

for year in years:
    my_urls = ('http://www.hitparadeitalia.it/hp_yenda/lpe' + str(year) + '.htm',)
    my_url = my_urls[0]
    for my_url in my_urls:
        uClient = uReq(my_url)
        html_input = uClient.read()
        uClient.close()
        page_soup = BeautifulSoup(html_input, "html.parser")
        [s.extract() for s in page_soup('script')]
        filename = "ALBUM" + str(year) + ".csv"
        f = open(filename, "w")
        headers = "NN, album, interprete, etichetta, mass, tracklist" + "/n"
        f.write(headers)
        containers = page_soup.findAll("table", {"class":"piccolo"})
        containerr = containers[0].findAll("tr")
        container = containerr[0]
        for container in containerr:
            items = container.findAll("td")
            NN = items[0].text
            album = items[1].text
            interprete = items[2].text
            etichetta = items[3].text
            mass = items[4].text
            tracklist = items[5].text.strip()

            print("NN: " + NN)
            print("album: " + album)
            print("interprete: " + interprete)
            print("etichetta: " + etichetta)
            print("mass: " + mass)
            print("tracklist: " + tracklist)

            f.write(NN + "," + album + "," + interprete + "," + etichetta + "," + mass + "," + tracklist + "\n")
        f.close()
```

I see from the print function outputs that:

1. the first row is correctly generated by attaching data to each column title;
2. from the second row on, it works up till the tracklist column, than it throws in all the text of the following rows and it re-starts from the next row by doing the same, wrong, iteration.

Best way to understand the issue is to run the code and see the output (scrolling down it should be clear the issue with the iteration).

Answer (score 0):

```
...    
for container in containerr:
    items = container("td")
    NN = items[0].text.encode('utf-8','ignore')
    album = items[1].text.encode('utf-8','ignore')
    interprete = items[2].text.encode('utf-8','ignore')
    etichetta = items[3].text.encode('utf-8','ignore')
    mass = items[4].text.encode('utf-8','ignore')
    tracklist = items[5].text.encode('utf-8','ignore')

    print("NN: " + NN)
    print("album: " + album)
    print("interprete: " + interprete)
    print("etichetta: " + etichetta)
    print("mass: " + mass)
    print("tracklist: " + tracklist)
...
```

You can `encode` your output into `utf-8` or `ascii`.

Comment: it doesn't work because it appearently needs something to tell the csv to get utf-8. I tried with f = open(filename, "w", 'utf-8'), as suggested in another post, but it does not work.

Comment: chance encode style to `ascii` if you are using `python2.+`

Comment: I am using python 3